# Why contents of ListViewItem are missing or hiding in listview after drag and drop in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I implemented a list view with drag and drop functionality on first drag and drop contents in ListViewItem are missing or hiding and after second drag and drop the same item comes into existence, can some one explain me this behavior? and how to solve this issue?

[Here is project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HxiNvrjzJwyjIwGTOgaMoyN_h_wGPGOW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet that you are using here by updating your question? It seems that you just shared a .sln file instead of the project. Please just share the necessary which is used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT I've updated you will get a zip file of project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is related to the binding. You are binding a `RelativePanel` control to the `ContentControl` of the `DataTemplate`. That's not a good design which will affect the re-render of the item.

Our suggestion is that please make sure the model is just about data and put all the controls into the `DataTemplate`.

For example the DataTemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate" x:DataType="local:Entity">
        <ContentControl >
            <RelativePanel >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}"/>
            </RelativePanel>
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Entity Class:

```
    public class Entity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

   
    public Entity(string name1)
    {
        Id = name1;
      
    }

 
}
```

If you want to have different `DataTemplate` based the specific data, just use the **DataTemplateSelector**-[Data template selection: Styling items based on their properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/data-template-selector).